# Adverts vs donation

Tags: advertisement

Excuse me if this question appears in a wrong community, but I just have a headache of how should I make it in order to get some money to keep my servers on.

I have a closed community website which is soon will be launched, the only problem is that I can not decide which way to go. Should I include a support/donation button for people to donate some money (similar like reddit) or a little advert somewhere in the website.

What you think it would be the best for users and money earning practice?

Comment: What is best for users is neither. What is best for you business is probably the support/donation - As you have a 'closed community' there is a strong possibility that advertisers won't be interested (based on the types of users in your community). However, this is based entirely on opinion as will most answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

As the user above noted, a closed community may or may not attract a lot of advertisers - though **depending on the nature of your community you might find vendors that target ads to your users, which could be beneficial to you**. Whether or not it benefits your users will depend on each individual user and how they respond to any given ad.

Donations are only really in the interest of the users if you make it VERY clear how their donation will benefit them: more content, more prompt attention from the site administrators, more features, better access to things, enabling you to keep the community going, whatever.

If this is a high-value community with committed users, **asking for a donation to allow you to keep doing your thing is not at all out of line** (look at Wikipedia, they do it all the time). But you might also consider a subscription model if this is something you work on regularly and from which people derive great value.

Comment: Just to add to this answer - you might also want to think about adding a section behind a pay wall with added or extended functionality and/or content depending on whether or not you think your community will support this.  Finally, test it! If you have the capability then run a multivariant test with the three groups (normal, ads, and donations) if you don't then you could try asking your users to complete surevys about their experience of the product and ask them which they would prefer.

Answer (score 2):

How about the model [Spotify](https://www.spotifyartists.com/spotify-explained/#how-does-spotify-make-money) uses? It offers a free version with ads, and a paid version with no ads. I think this is a win-win situation for everyone. Let me explain.

A free user will generate a little bit of revenue, while not having to pay for anything, and the user who pays should get extra benefits (even let's say a gold badge next to their name on a forum could be a great way to reward him), and no ads.

So, place ads that are **not obtrusive** (very important), and offer a paid version.

The problem with websites that rely solely on one or the other option sometimes might get short on funding, and become obtrusive (like Wikipedia with their donation model, or news site like Forbes, which show an ad before even loading an article).

Comment: Advertisers will not pay to have their ads placed in ways that are unobtrusive - this is the very point of advertising: It has to be as visible as possible. Spotify interrupts your listening with up to 90 seconds of advertising at a time - hardly unobtrusive. The visual advertising is not unobtrusive either. The last time I looked they were using skyscrapers (120-190 px wide) on the sides and leaderboards (around 90 px high) at the top and/or bottom - I also remember the UI moving around when one ad changed for another of a different size.

Comment: What I was talking about is putting ads **before** the content. If a new user will come to a website that won't let him read an article unless he scrolls over 10 advertisements is a huge deterrent for future viewers. @AndrewMartin

Comment: @AndrewMartin, you're correct, but a banner or 2 is not considered obtrusive. 10 banners yes. Of course speaking of normal banners the size you mention, if the banner is 100%width x 400, then it's another story

Comment: Many thanks for your great suggestions here! I will sure going to update with some details in a future!